# Trying to .SaveAs an Outlook MailItem, getting Run-time error '287' Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My department uses Access to create PDFs and sends out documents in a generic e-mail template. They currently do this by opening the template, attaching the PDF manually, and then send it off. After the e-mail is sent, they then drag the .msg file from the Outlook Sent folder into each client folder individually.

I wrote an Excel VBA to read the e-mail addresses in each cell, attach the PDF through a path, send the e-mail, and then save the .msg automatically.

**The problem:** The .SaveAs function will not work for me as I get runtime error 287. Everything else works (Attachments, .Display, .Send, etc.) if I leave the .SaveAs out.

**Things I have done:** I have the Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Objects referenced, and I have tried both early and late binding. This is on a workstation and they use Excel 2010, but when I try on my home computer with Excel 2013 (Outlook 15.0 Objects) it DOES work.

I am baffled... Also, here's a link to a screen shot of the error and the line:

[image: screenshot]

```
Sub CreateNewMessage()

Dim OutApp          As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg   As Object
Dim Pth             As String
Dim cell            As Range

Pth = "some\path\" 'Path to PDF folder

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Set Outlook application

On Error GoTo Cleanup

    'For Loop to find each cell of e-mails
    For Each cell In Columns("E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Finds e-mail values @ and . for cell value
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then 
    Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    With objOutlookMsg
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & " - Approval Letter"
        .body = "Pre-worded e-mail template"
        .Attachments.Add Pth & Dir(Pth & Cells(cell.Row, "C") & "\" & .Subject & ".msg" 'Attach PDF
        'This next SaveAs line throws the error, or if I keep the error handler in, it goes to Cleanup and nothing happens
        .SaveAs "Path\To\Save\Folder" & Cells(cell.Row "C") & _
        "\" & .Subject & ".msg" 'Save MailItem to folder
        .Display '.Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
End If
Next cell

Cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like `Cells(cell.Row "C")` is missing a comma.

Comment: @aduguid please don't make edit's to inactive posts almost two years old. They bump these questions back into the front page of the site, where they have no buisness at all.

Answer (score 1):

I see your code has the "," in the `Cells(cell.Row, "C")` so that's just a typo above,

but you haven't changed the default line to match your path (in your image either)

```
"Path\To\Save\Folder"
```